# cordova plugin camera preventing git commit

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, jsdoc2md

I have [cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/issues) in my Ionic app and its preventing me from running `git commit` due to an error when attempting to generate its own docs using the `jsdoc2md` command.

```
$ git commit -m "x"

> cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 precommit /plugins/cordova-plugin-camera
> npm run gen-docs && git add README.md


> cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 gen-docs /plugins/cordova-plugin-camera
> jsdoc2md --template "jsdoc2md/TEMPLATE.md" "www/**/*.js" --plugin "dmd-plugin-cordova-plugin" > README.md

sh: jsdoc2md: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 gen-docs: `jsdoc2md --template "jsdoc2md/TEMPLATE.md" "www/**/*.js" --plugin "dmd-plugin-cordova-plugin" > README.md`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 gen-docs script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jeremylopez/.npm/_logs/2018-10-04T15_25_27_086Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 precommit: `npm run gen-docs && git add README.md`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cordova-plugin-camera@4.0.3 precommit script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2018-10-04T15_25_27_107Z-debug.log

husky - pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

Any idea how to get past this error?  The app is built in the cloud so any local changes I make to the package will not help.

Comment: silly question but did you run `npm install` correctly? Do you have all the deps (including jsdoc2md) installed correctly on the machine you are running git?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "correctly" but yes I installed it using `npm install`.